# Is there a term to describe tables where only the last value should be used?

Tags: sql, database-design, theory

In my database there are tables where each row represents an entity, and there are other tables where the same entity can appear multiple times, but only the latest entry is the valid one.

For example, I have a table `customer` where each row represents a customer and another table `customer_membership_status` where the same customer can be referenced multiple times, but only the last record for each customer is suppost to be used. Data is never updated in `customer_membership_status`, only inserted.

Is there a term to describe this pattern? I'm asking because I would like to quickly and easily explain the intended use of the table to others.

Comment: event sourcing, logging, write only, versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best term would be [CQRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs) and [event sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/event-sourcing)

> Using the stream of events as the write store, rather than the actual data at a point in time, avoids update conflicts on a single aggregate and maximizes performance and scalability
>
> ## Event Sourcing pattern
>
> **Instead of storing just the current state of the data in a domain, use an append-only store to record the full series of actions taken on that data.** The store acts as the system of record and can be used to materialize the domain objects. This can simplify tasks in complex domains, by avoiding the need to synchronize the data model and the business domain, while improving performance, scalability, and responsiveness. It can also provide consistency for transactional data, and maintain full audit trails and history that can enable compensating actions.

**EDIT:**

After closer look you may also read about [SCD(Slowly Changing Dimension)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row) Type 2.

> This method tracks historical data by creating multiple records for a given natural key in the dimensional tables with separate surrogate keys and/or different version numbers. Unlimited history is preserved for each insert.

Comment: What about the name of the pattern for `customer`? Would it be correct to just refer to it as a **conventional** table?

Answer (score 0):

Temporal table. It's a table where a timestamp / version attribute is part of a key. The temporal / version attribute allows you to identify which is the latest row for each customer.